# IExplorer после отрабатывания javascript функции предлагает скачать файл js

Tags: javascript, http, internet-explorer, drupal

использую следующие заголовки http

```
drupal_add_http_header('Content-Type', 'text/javascript; charset=utf-8');
drupal_add_http_header('Content-Disposition','attachment; filename=' . basename($file));
drupal_add_http_header('Cache-Control','no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
drupal_add_http_header('Content-Length',filesize($file));
```

если убрать первые 2 заголовка, то появляется текст js кода

данные загружаются в iframe

гуглил 4 часа - делалэксперименты с заголовками http, в том числе кешем

пробовал в IExplorer открыть гугл JQuery - предложил скачать файл(во всех остальных браузерах - показывает код js)

скрипт подключаю конструкцией

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="some_id" src="Some_url" async></script>
```

Во всех других браузерах скачать файл не предлагает и нормально выполняет

Использую HTML 5

Comment: а ожидаемое поведение какое? [content-disposition:attachment](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8/Content-Disposition) и говорит, что файл должен сохраниться

Comment: Спасибо @Grundy, я пробовал использовать Content-Disposition: inline, но это не помогало. >"а ожидаемое поведение какое" - предполагается что скрипт просто выполнится без уведомления о скачивании файла js - собственно во всех браузерах кроме IE так и работает

Comment: попробуй просто убрать установку этого заголовка, оставив все остальные

Comment: В таком варианте @Grundy - IExplorer все равно предлагает скачать файл, только его формат он не может определить(в поле Тип: неизвестный формат файла)

Comment: Убери все, кроме `Content-Type` и попробуй добавлять по одному. Возможно `Content-Length` Тоже влияет, а возможно какие-то значения в cache-control

Comment: благодарю, @Grundy, причина была в том что я жал на тег <a> у которого пустой href. Только IE перекидывал меня на этот файл - остальные воспринимали пустой href как span элемент

Comment: Очень странно, на самом деле